# Linux Manjaro freezing issues and random reboots

Tags: freeze

I have installed Manjaro Linux on my computer, coming from windows 10, where all hardware worked fine. I previously tried Manjaro out but ran into the same issue here. My OS would freeze or come to a complete crawl. Sometimes it can recover until the issue occurs again. Other times it will just reboot. After having trying to find a fix, I found it may have something to do with AMD Ryzen processors not having support for certain power functionality. A potential fix to this is to disable C-States entirely, or use Typical IDLE current. I have tried both of these, and still did not fix the system crashes. I then performed a BIOS update, this didn't solve this issue, however, since the BIOS update the system has shown to occasionally recover only to reboot minutes later. I found some articles suggesting that it could be due to the kernel version. Some of these posts were old and were suggesting to move kernel version to 5.4 LTS. I didn't think this would help, since my Kernel version is 5.15. Another article also suggested that these issues could be down to no swap partition being available. I have since added a swap partition (and enabled it). I canv erify that it is enabled by `free`, which gives the output in the screen capture below.
[image]

When this issue occurs, the machines fans will noticeably speed up, suggesting some power management or fan issue with Linux drivers?

Another article I read suggested that creating another user account might rectify this, as extensions and addon's could cause similar issues. Although, since this is a clean install I doubt this is the case.

I took some photos of a system log after it crashed then rebooted using this command: `journalctl --system --boot=-1`
[image]

[image]

[image]

I have even followed this article on installing AMD microcode to try rectify this issue: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/amd-microcode-installation/50783.
All have attempted all solutions above and, issue still occurs.
Here is my system information, if its helpful.
[image]

Comment: Could you try running Fedora 36? The manjaro kernel looks to be quite old: 5.4 vs the current 5.18. Also try running memtest86 for an hour or two just in case: https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm Also try resetting BIOS settings.

Comment: On a debian machine with AMD Ryzen 2500U, I got it fixed with this program: [Zenstates](https://github.com/r4m0n/ZenStates-Linux). There even is a service and script ready ([here](https://gist.github.com/jfredrickson/8bba6f31b1716b2d0ef871c8d4bc2ce3)) for running it on boot, so you may save that time.

Comment: I have tried to use the Zenstaes script, since using it the problem still occurs, except when it reboots it will reboot a few more times before it stabilises for a little while.

Comment: This kind of thing is often to do with nvidia drivers. Are you sure you have correctly installed a suitable driver? The rtkit daemon gives certain threads higher priority than others. The canary reference is about a safeguard where it detects a thread that is getting too much priority (so the system might appear to be freezing) and then demotes it. Unless you have a good reason for using rtkit daemon I would try disabling it.

Comment: I have tried booting Manjaro, Linux Mint, Arch, Ubuntu, Pop_os, abd Fedora. All have done the same thing as Manjaro. Hardware errors and sift kicks up are first displayed as the machine boots. On Fedora, it straight up refuses to boot. Systems-machined.service and virtqemud.service has failed to start and the machine refuses to do anything else.